# Approximation for the integral $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x}{(a x+1)^2} \, dx$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I want to find the mean of random variable $x$. In my analysis, I came up with an integral  $$I=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x}{(a x+1)^2} \, dx$$
which does not have a closed-form solution, probably it does not converge $\{0,\infty \}$.

However, I am wondering whether or not there is an approximation when $a\in[0,\infty)$. Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$$I(t)=\int_0^{t} \frac{x}{(a x+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{t } \frac{ax}{(a x+1)^2}\, dx =\frac{1}{a}\left(\int_0^{t } \frac{1}{(a x+1)}dx-\int_0^{t } \frac{1}{(a x+1)^2}dx\right)$$

the first integral integrates to $\frac{1}{a}\ln(ax+1)$ and the second one to $\frac{1}{a(ax+1)} $ you can see in particular the it does not converge in $+\infty$